# mybatis-spring-boot-starter giving error when maven package

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mybatis

I am newbie. I follow instructions from page [http://sivalabs.in/2016/03/springboot-working-with-mybatis/](http://sivalabs.in/2016/03/springboot-working-with-mybatis) to config mybatis-spring-boot-starter. I use Mapper XML files to define the queries.

I run it by spring boot app that it is no problem. 
But when I package war file by cmd: `mvn clean package`. And I run web app by cmd: `java -jar [fileWarName].war` that I giving errors as below :

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2017-08-20 12:26:48.690 ERROR 3404 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/KhoaNA/Desktop/test/spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/techprimers/mybatis/springbootmybatis/resource/UsersResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/KhoaNA/Desktop/test/spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/techprimers/mybatis/springbootmybatis/mapper/UsersMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'URL [jar:file:C:\Users\KhoaNA\Desktop\test\spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes/vn/hipt/fas/sql/MenuMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.techprimers.mybatis.springbootmybatis.mapper.UsersMapper.findUserById
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.techprimers.mybatis.springbootmybatis.SpringBootMybatisApplication.main(SpringBootMybatisApplication.java:12) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) [spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/KhoaNA/Desktop/test/spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/techprimers/mybatis/springbootmybatis/mapper/UsersMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'URL [jar:file:C:\Users\KhoaNA\Desktop\test\spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes/vn/hipt/fas/sql/MenuMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.techprimers.mybatis.springbootmybatis.mapper.UsersMapper.findUserById
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       ... 27 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'URL [jar:file:C:\Users\KhoaNA\Desktop\test\spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes/vn/hipt/fas/sql/MenuMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.techprimers.mybatis.springbootmybatis.mapper.UsersMapper.findUserById
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1342) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       ... 39 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'URL [jar:file:C:\Users\KhoaNA\Desktop\test\spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes/vn/hipt/fas/sql/MenuMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.techprimers.mybatis.springbootmybatis.mapper.UsersMapper.findUserById
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       ... 51 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'URL [jar:file:C:\Users\KhoaNA\Desktop\test\spring-boot-mybatis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes/vn/hipt/fas/sql/MenuMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.techprimers.mybatis.springbootmybatis.mapper.UsersMapper.findUserById
>       at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:523) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
>       at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:380) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
>       at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:547) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
>       at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration.sqlSessionFactory(MybatisAutoConfiguration.java:139) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
>       at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ea2ff066.CGLIB$sqlSessionFactory$1() ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
>       at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ea2ff066$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$311d2308.invoke() ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ea2ff066.sqlSessionFactory() ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       ... 52 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.techprimers.mybatis.springbootmybatis.mapper.UsersMapper.findUserById
>       at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:120) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:92) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:521) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
>       ... 65 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.techprimers.mybatis.springbootmybatis.mapper.UsersMapper.findUserById
>       at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.put(Configuration.java:859) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.put(Configuration.java:831) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addMappedStatement(Configuration.java:655) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.addMappedStatement(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:302) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:109) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:135) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:128) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:118) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
>       ... 67 common frames omitted

This is my source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B72-i2S1W9r2TWVZaUhWa201M3M/view?usp=sharing

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I followed the tutorial too. The problem isn't what Billy says. The problem is that sivalabs used a forbidden value for mybatis.mapperLocations. You must use mybatis.mapper-locations and resources' relative folder. 
E.g: You want to scan mappers that are organized in feature folders

```
java
     main
     resources
              mapper
                    feautureA
                             featureAMapper.xml <- Mapper to scan
                    feautureB
                             featureBMapper.xml <- Mapper to scan
```

You must to use a pattern:

```
mybatis.mapper-locations=mapper/**/*.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution from page: https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/issues/106

I should use default of MyBatis Spring Boot AutoConfigure. Don't change config mapperLocations: classpath*:**/mapper/*.xml.

Thanks everyone!